# use apply in dataframe between different rows r

Tags: r, apply

I have a df

```
a=1:10000
b=1:10000
a=data.frame(a,b)
> head(a)
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6
```

and would like to make a new column, its function based by comparing the value of a[n] with b[n-1] and wonder if I can use an apply function instead of a for loop.

```
d=0
for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]){d=c(d,a[i,1]-a[i-1,2])}
```

and then I would like to bind the last column to the original df

```
a=data.frame(a,d)
> head(a)
  a b d
1 1 1 0
2 2 2 1
3 3 3 1
4 4 4 1
5 5 5 1
6 6 6 1
```

My real df is 3825966 and 21 columns. I head repeatedly that apply is faster, but do not know how to write this up, or if it is possible

Comment: `a$d <- c(NA, tail(a$a, -1) - head(a$b, -1))`

Comment: works amazing. Thanks jogo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
a$d <- c(NA, tail(a$a, -1) - head(a$b, -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster again,

```
a$d <- a$a - c(NA, a$b[-length(a$b)])
```

Benchmark:

```
> a=rnorm(1000000, 0, 5)
> b=rnorm(1000000, 0, 10)
> a=data.frame(a,b)
> t <- Sys.time()
> a$d <- a$a - c(NA, a$b[-length(a$b)])
> Sys.time() - t
Time difference of 0.03000093 secs
> 
> t=Sys.time()
> a$d <- c(NA, tail(a$a, -1) - head(a$b, -1))
> Sys.time()-t
Time difference of 0.06505489 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `dplyr` and `lag`?

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% mutate(lagb=lag(b)) %>% mutate(d = a-lagb) %>% head()
#   a b lagb  d
# 1 1 1   NA NA
# 2 2 2    1  1
# 3 3 3    2  1
# 4 4 4    3  1
# 5 5 5    4  1
# 6 6 6    5  1
```

Answer (score 0):

@jogo solution works great.

some benchmarking results from my side:
jogo style

```
> a=1:100000
> b=1:100000
> a=data.frame(a,b)
> t=Sys.time()
> a$d <- c(NA, tail(a$a, -1) - head(a$b, -1))
> Sys.time()-t
Time difference of 0.02101493 secs
> #time took 0 sec
```

> my style

```
> a=1:100000
> b=1:100000
> a=data.frame(a,b)
> t=Sys.time()
> d=0
> for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]){d=c(d,a[i,1]-a[i-1,2])}
> Sys.time()-t
Time difference of 48.94479 secs
```

>